# Signing Apple certificates to .NET MAUI application in macOS

Tags: .net, macos, maui, codesign, maui-community-toolkit

I've created .NET MAUI application in macOS, I've tried to sign it's bundle with Apple provided for me certificates with all steps mentioned in their site like this:

```
codesign --deep --force --sign "Developer ID Application: Developer_Certificate" TestApp.app
```

After that I've created the dmg file for creating install package like this:

```
create-dmg 'TestApp.app'
```

And signed the installer with certificate:

```
codesign --deep --force --sign "Developer ID Application: Installer_Certificate" TestApp.dmg
```

If I installing this app after this step everything is OK, but when I'm uploading it to the cloud storage, downloading it, installing to the macOS and trying to run I'm getting this error:

```
"TestApp" can't be opened because Apple cannot check it for malicious software
```

Can someone help me with this? I'll be very appreciated.

Comment: 1. May I know what cloud storage you are using? 2. If you’re certain that an app you want to install is from a trustworthy source and hasn’t been tampered with, you can [temporarily override your Mac security settings to open it](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202491#openanyway).
In the Finder, Control-click the app, choose Open from the menu, and in the dialog that appears, click Open. Enter your admin name and password when prompted. https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202491

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, finally I found the problem of the signing process. There was external binaries in the bundle, so before signing the application, these binaries should be signed first and only after that sign the application. My fault was that I thoght that it should be made automatically with codesign process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who met this similar issue when signing Apple certificates to .NET MAUI application, please take care of the signing process order.

The issue is related with the code sign process. We need to sign the external binaries in the bundle firstly and then so we can sign the application.